# Teamcity build counter not being passed into Ant

Tags: java, ant, teamcity

I'm using Teamcity to build with an Ant runner.

I'm trying to pass the current build counter into the "Additional Ant command line parameters" using the following

```
-lib %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/MI/CustomAntTasks/jars/CustomAntTasks.jar -Dlabel={0}
```

The value `-Dlabel={0}` is being passed into the Ant script as the literal value {0} and not the current value of the build counter.

Any ideas on how I can correctly pass through the build counter (not the build number)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is accessible via the build-in parameter, i.e. you don't need to try to pass it in.

```
${build.number}
```

There are other values too: [Predefined Build Parameters](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Predefined+Build+Parameters)